# How to use string references in boolean comparisons

Tags: python, string, pandas, boolean

I am trying to create a loop to create a lot of variables based on boolean comparisons. I am looking at three variables at a time and creating flags based on whether an observation has 1,2 or three of these flags.

I get an error when I try to look at 3 variables. Oddly it works fine with 1 or two. I've even tried using the same variable twice (to check that it's nothing to do with the variable ) but that does not work either. It's something about adding a 3rd variable.

Generate similar dataset

```
results = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(20, 3)), columns=['Pre_BF_2014_Flag', 'BF_2014_Flag', 'XMAS_2014_Flag' ])
```

This is what it looks like hard coded and this works

```
results.loc[(results.Pre_BF_2014_Flag == 1) & (results.BF_2014_Flag == 0) & 
(results.XMAS_2014_Flag == 0), 'Combo_2014_Pre_BF_Only'] = 1
```

I am trying to put this in a loop (as I have lots of years and flags)

```
years= [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
var = ['_Flag']

for i in years:
    for k in var:

        results.loc[("results.Pre_BF_" + str(i) + str(k) == 1) & 
("results.BF_" + str(i) + str(k) == 0) & ("results.XMAS_"+ str(i) + 
str(k) == 0), 'Combo_2014_Pre_BF_Only'] = 1
```

This show the error

KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

When I hard code that third condition it works fine.

```
results.loc[("results.Pre_BF_" + str(i) + str(k) == 1) & ("results.BF_" + str(i) + str(k) == 0) & (results.XMAS_2014_Flag == 0), 'Combo_2014_Pre_BF_Only'] = 1
```

Also works if I use that XMAS variable as the first or second condition. It's just something about using 3 conditions.

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: Another binary flag (or 1 and NaN) called 'Combo_2014_Pre_BF_Only' as to whether those three conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful. `"results.Pre_BF_" + str(i) + str(k)` represents a **string**, not a series. You can't use vectorised Boolean indexing with strings.

You can write your intended logic as follows:

```
years= [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
var = ['_Flag']

for i in years:
    for k in var:
        m1 = results[f'Pre_BF_{i}{k}'] == 1
        m2 = results[f'BF_{i}{k}'] == 0
        m3 = results[f'XMAS_{i}{k}'] == 0
        results.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, f'Combo_{i}_Pre_BF_Only'] = 1
```

A better idea is to construct a Boolean series via direct assignment:

```
        results[f'Combo_{i}_Pre_BF_Only'] = m1 & m2 & m3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results['Pre_BF_2014_Flag'] & results['BF_2014_Flag'] & results['XMAS_2014_Flag']
```

Or

```
from functools import reduce
results.apply(lambda col: reduce(lambda p,q: p & q, col), axis=1)
```